# Python regex multiple occurrences outside brackets

Tags: python, regex, brackets

I would like to search and replace all occurrences outside of <>. 
I can make an assumption that all brackets are matched.
For example, I want to replace 'BLOCK' with a '*':

```
BLOCKaaa<BLOCKaaaa>aaaaa<>BLOCKzzzBLOCKBLOCK
```

would become:

```
*aa<BLOCKaaaa>aaaaa<>*zzz**
```

I have tried the following:

-Add > at the beginning and < at the end of the line, call it LINEwith><

-Run:

```
re.sub('(>[^<>]*)(BLOCK)+? ([^<>]*<?)', '\\1*\\3', LINEwith><)
```

But it gives me this instead:

```
'>*aaa<BLOCKaaaa>aaaaa<>BLOCKzzzBLOCK*<'
```

I am not sure how to replace all occurrences between ><

Can someone help me with this? Or suggest a better method of doing it.

Comment: Can `<` and `>` occur nested? So `aaaaa<aaaa<aaaa>aaa>aaaa` or only as you've described in your example?

Comment: I have not encountered that yet, but I wouldn't say I can rule it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can assume that the brackets are always matched, the following should work.

```
re.sub(r'BLOCK(?=[^>]*(<|$))', '*', line)
```

This also assumes that there can be no nested brackets.

This uses a lookahead to make sure that there are no `>` characters before the next `<` character or the end of the string.  Since a lookahead is being used, the only text that the regex will actually match is `BLOCK`, so the replacement is simplified to `'*'` since there are no longer any capture groups.

Here is a version that will work up to one level of nested brackets:

```
BLOCK(?=([^<>]*(<(<[^>]*>|[^<>])*>)?)*$)
```

Example:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'BLOCK(?=([^<>]*(<(<[^>]*>|[^<>])*>)?)*$)')
>>> p.sub('*', 'BLOCK<BLOCK<BLOCK>>BLOCK<BLOCK>BLOCKzzzBLOCKBLOCK')
'*<BLOCK<BLOCK>>*<BLOCK>*zzz**'
```

As you can see, regular expressions are not really well suited for nested data structures.

Comment: Thank you so much. What if there are nested brackets and I want to limit the search outside of the outermost layer?

Comment: @QNguyen, edited with a version for one level of nesting, it gets ugly pretty quickly!

Comment: It is not possible to parse arbitrarily-nested structures with regexes.  If you need arbitrary nesting, take a look at something like pyparsing.

Answer (score 0):

if the brackets are nested, you can't use a regular expression. How about some `split`-fu?

```
def replace_outside(string, original, replacement):
    level = 0  #the level of nesting - 0 is outside
    result = [] #a temp list holding the result
    while string:
        #split the string until the first '<', save everything before that in
        #current and process the rest in the next iteration
        splitstr = string.split("<", 1)
        if len(splitstr) == 1: current, string = string, ""
        else: current, string = tuple(splitstr)
        if level == 0:
            #we're outside - replace everything in current string
            current = current.replace(original, replacement)
        else:
            #decrease the level by the number of closing brackets in current
            level -= current.count(">")
            if level == 0:
                #everything after the last '>' is outside
                inner, outer = current.rsplit(">", 1)
                #replace outer and join with inner again
                outer = outer.replace(original, replacement)
                current = '>'.join([inner, outer])
        #append the string to the result list and increase level by one
        result.append(current)
        level += 1
    #return the result list joined by the '>' we split it by
    return '<'.join(result)
```

(this obviously fails if there are any unmatched brackets.)